# Windows 7 getting 'Setup was unable to create new system partition' when trying to install on dual boot with Linux Mint 15

Tags: windows-7, linux, hard-drive, partitioning, linux-mint

I know there are a LOT of threads with this error message in but my case is different. I sold my windows PC and want to dual Boot Windows 7 Ultimate and Linux Mint 15. I have Linux Mint 15 installed on the whole HDD, so I went into ubuntu live CD, ran gparted and made an NTFS partition for Windows to install to. When I try and install I get the 'Setup was unable to create a new system partition' error. I have no other USB's attached, no other HDDs attatched etc. And my HDD is at the top of the boot order. The only thing I can think of is that my NTFS patition is under the extended partition folder thingy, with the swap partiton and the mint partition, but i cant seem to figure out how to get it out of there. I also have Parted Magic installed to a disk, any ideas?

Comment: Edit your question and post the output of `sudo parted /dev/sda print`.

Answer (score 0):

You could try solution described in [this blog article](http://druss.pp.ua/2013/10/fix-error-during-installing-windows-7-from-usb-setup-was-unable-to-create-a-system-partition-or-locate-an-existing-partition/)

> 1. When you see the error – remove the flash drive from the computer
> 2. Press exit (red cross in the top right corner)
> 3. Start installation from the beginning (without reboot)
> 4. After selecting Windows 7 edition you will get new error
> 5. Press OK in error window, you will be redirected to installation main menu
> 6. Insert your USB Flash drive in to the computer
> 7. Install windows

Comment: Sorry, doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can try to copy all installation files from USB to HDD and install windows from HDD to the same HDD. [Here is step by step instruction](http://druss.pp.ua/2014/07/fixed-setup-was-unable-to-create-a-new-system-partition-or-locate-an-existing-system-partition-during-installing-windows-8-18-7-vista-etc-from-usb/)